# Where to start with reversing a custom JavaScript VM?

Tags: assembly, javascript, byte-code, virtualizers

I have recently ran into the most heavy JavaScript obfuscation I've seen. It is using a custom VM to execute bytecodes. I have never dealt with such obfuscation, and I am wondering where I can start to decompile the script. Not asking to be spoonfed, just looking for some tips! Thanks!